# Auxochromic action of an alkyl group attached to a double bond

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy

In the UV-Vis spectra,

$\ce{CH2=CH2}$ has max absorbance at $\pu{171 nm}$.

$\ce{CH3-CH2-CH=CH-CH2-CH3}$ has max absorbance at $\pu{184 nm}$.

The alkyl groups decrease the π-π* gap by raising the π but not considerably the π*. The effect which I suspect is hyperconjugation, but when it happens between the σ-π orbitals, it should occur with the π* orbital; if anything, raising it even more? How does the gap decrease then?

Comment: Reference for chem equation/expression formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Thank you, that helps!